# Custom Button that will change a field in a custom object and consequently invoke before update trigger on the same object

Tags: apex, trigger, webservices, custom-button, ajax

I have a ajax cutom button that calls a apex class and the class is changing status field of that object. Now I want to invoke a before update trigger on the same object, which is not working.

Custom Button :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}

sforce.apex.execute("ABV_SMPORD","submitSMPORD",{localId:"{!Sample_Order__c.Id}"});
alert("Done");
```

Apex Class:

```
global class ABV_SMPORD{
    webservice static void submitSMPORD(Id localId) { 
                V_SAMPLE_CANCEL.isSampleCancel = true;
                Sample_Order__c sot = new Sample_Order__c(Id=localId);
                sot.Status__C='Submitted';
                sot.Delivery_Status__C='Delivered'; 
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger V_SAMPLE_ORDER_TRANSACTION_BEFORE on Sample_Order__c (before update,before delete) {
    String ProfileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();
    V_ERROR_MSG_BUNDLE bundle = new V_ERROR_MSG_BUNDLE();
    Profile pr = [Select Id, PermissionsModifyAllData From Profile where Id = :ProfileId];
    boolean modAllData = false;
    if (pr != null && pr.PermissionsModifyAllData)
       modAllData = true;
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        boolean isUnlocked = false;            
        for (Sample_Order__c so : Trigger.new) {
            if (so.Unlock__c == true) {
                so.Status__c = 'Saved';
                so.Unlock__c = false;
                isUnlocked = true;
            } else {
                if (modAllData == false && so.Status__c == 'Submitted') {
                    if (V_SAMPLE_CANCEL.isSampleCancel == false) 
                       so.Id.addError(bundle.getErrorMsg('UPD_SAMPORDER'), false);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        //  
        for (Sample_Order_Transaction__c so : Trigger.old) {
            if ( so.Status__c == 'Submitted') {
                so.Id.addError(bundle.getErrorMsg('DEL_SAMPORDER'), false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to trigger the trigger you need to actually save the record to the database. So update your code to this:

```
global class ABV_SMPORD{
webservice static void submitSMPORD(Id localId) { 
            V_SAMPLE_CANCEL.isSampleCancel = true;
            Sample_Order__c sot = new Sample_Order__c(Id=localId);
            sot.Status__C='Submitted';
            sot.Delivery_Status__C='Delivered'; 
            // adding an update here!
            update sot;
}
```